# Dafny if an assertion is true on entry and exit of a loop is it an invariant

Tags: dafny, loop-invariant

In Dafny I am experimenting writing iterative implementations to recursive specifications. More specifically a  `predicate containsMe<T (==)>(l:seq<T>, me:T)`   that returns true when the `me` is an element of the sequence `l`.

Having recently been directed to http://leino.science/papers/krml275.html I can see that other approaches might be better, nonetheless I have stumbled into an interesting problem.

I have a partial solution (given below) for which as assertion given at the start and end of the loop can be verified but it is not an invariant. Have I missed something, is this a bug or is there a way to help Dafny establish invariants that I have not understood?

```
predicate method containsMe<T (==)>(l:seq<T>, me:T) 
decreases l
{
  if l== [] then  false
    else if l[0] == me  then true else containsMe(l[1..],me)
}

lemma {:induction l} cont<T (==)>(l:seq<T>, me:T) 
   ensures (exists i:nat :: i<|l| && l[i] == me)  <==> containsMe(l,me)  { }

lemma {:induction l} conti<T (==)>(l:seq<T>, me:T, i:nat) 
   ensures ( i<|l| && l[i] == me)  ==> containsMe(l,me)  {
    calc {
      i<|l| && l[i] == me ;
      ==>
      exists i:nat :: i<|l| && l[i] == me;
      ==> {cont(l,me);}
      containsMe(l,me);
    }
    }
    
lemma  ping<T (==)>(l:seq<T>, me:T, i:nat) 
  ensures ( i<|l| && l[i] == me) ==> containsMe(l[..i+1],me)  
  { 
       calc {
         i<|l| && l[i] == me;
         ==>
         (i< |l[..i+1]| && l[..i+1][i] == me);
         ==> {conti(l[..i+1],me,i);}
          containsMe(l[..i+1],me);
       }        
  } 
 
method contains<T (==)>(l:seq<T>, el:T) returns (r:bool)
//ensures r == containsMe(l,el)
{
    print "contains ",l," , ",el,"\n";
    var i:nat:= 0;
    r := false;
    while (i < |l| && r ==false)
       decreases  |l| -i ,!r
       invariant (r ==> containsMe(l[..i+1],el) ) /*fails to verify */
    {
       assert    (r ==> containsMe(l[..i+1],el) );  /* true on entry */
        var b:bool := containsMe(l[..i+1],el);
        print "  ",i, "  ", l[i], " ", b, "\n";        
        if l[i] == el {
            r:=true; }
        else {i := i+1;}       
        calc { 
          (r==>  i<|l| && l[i] == el);
             ==> {ping(l,el,i);}
         (r ==> containsMe(l[..i+1],el)) ;
        }
        assert  (r ==>  containsMe(l[..i+1],el) ); /* true on exit */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dafny is not complaining that the invariant isn't true. It's complaining that it is not well formed because it thinks the index `i+1` might be bigger than the length of the array. Adding

```
invariant r ==> i < |l|
```

before the other invariant should fix the problem.

Comment: Many thanks. I keep thinking I know how to use Dafny but get tripped up so easily.

Comment: This still begs the question:  how come the statement ```r ==>  containsMe(l[..i+1],el)``` is well formed on entering and exiting the loop body yet ill formed in the invariant. Or is this situation just a dafny fact to remember?

Comment: First note that if `r` is known to be false, then the expression `r ==> ...` is vacuously well formed. At the top of the loop body, we know the while condition is true, so `i < |l| && r == false`, so in particular `r` is false which we said before means the expression is well formed. At the end of the loop, either `r` is still false, or `r` was set to true by the first branch of the if statement, which means the second branch of the if statement did *not* execute, so `i` has the same value it did at the top of the loop, so `i < |l|`, which is enough for well formedness.